# BeautifulSoup: get some tag from the page

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have html-code

```
<div class="b-media-cont b-media-cont_relative" data-triggers-container="true"><span class="label">Двигатель:</span> бензин, 1.6 л<br/>
<div class="b-triggers b-triggers_theme_dashed-buttons b-triggers_size_s b-triggers_text-notif"><div class="b-triggers__text">110 л.с.</div><div class="b-triggers__item b-triggers__item_notif" data-target="cost" data-target-container="[data-triggers-container]" data-toggle="tax_dropdown"><div class="b-link b-link_dashed">110 л.с.</div></div><div class="b-triggers-hidden-area b-triggers-hidden-area_width_240 b-triggers-hidden-area_close" data-target-bind="cost" style="left: 0px; top: 39px; width: 241px;">Налог на&nbsp;2016&nbsp;год <b>2&nbsp;750&nbsp;руб.</b><br/><br/><span class="gray">Расчет произведен на легковой автомобиль по <a href="http://law.drom.ru/calc/region77/skoda/rapid/2016/110/">калькулятору транспортного налога</a> для Москвы (<a href="http://www.drom.ru/my_region/">изменить регион</a>).</span></div></div><br/>
<span class="label">Тип кузова:</span> хэтчбек<br/>
<span class="label">Цвет:</span> золотистый<br/>
<span class="label">Пробег:</span> <b>Новый автомобиль от официального дилера</b><br/>
<span class="label">Руль:</span> левый<br/>
<span class="label">VIN:</span> XW8AC1NH7HK****32<br/>
</div><p><span class="label">Данные по модели из каталога:</span> 
<b>толян</b>
<b>4 515 руб.</b>
<b>Продажа Тойота Авенсис.</b>
```

And I need to get

```
<b>Новый автомобиль от официального дилера</b>
```

I try

```
mileages = soup.find_all('span', class_='label').next_subling
```

But it returns `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'next_subling'`
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

> AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'next_subling'

This is because `find_all()` returns multiple results - a list of matching tags. And, this problem is actually [covered by the `BeautifulSoup` documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous):

> `AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'foo'` - This usually happens because you expected `find_all()` to return a single tag or string. But `find_all()` returns a *list* of tags and strings–a `ResultSet` object. You need to iterate over the list and look at the .foo of each one. Or, if you really only want one result, you need to use `find()` instead of `find_all()`.

Instead, you should be using `find()` to locate a specific `label` by text and then get the next sibling element:

```
mileages = soup.find('span', text=u'Пробег:').find_next_sibling("b").get_text(strip=True)
```

---

This code works for me as is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = u"""
<div class="b-media-cont b-media-cont_relative" data-triggers-container="true"><span class="label">Двигатель:</span> бензин, 1.6 л<br/>
<div class="b-triggers b-triggers_theme_dashed-buttons b-triggers_size_s b-triggers_text-notif"><div class="b-triggers__text">110 л.с.</div><div class="b-triggers__item b-triggers__item_notif" data-target="cost" data-target-container="[data-triggers-container]" data-toggle="tax_dropdown"><div class="b-link b-link_dashed">110 л.с.</div></div><div class="b-triggers-hidden-area b-triggers-hidden-area_width_240 b-triggers-hidden-area_close" data-target-bind="cost" style="left: 0px; top: 39px; width: 241px;">Налог на&nbsp;2016&nbsp;год <b>2&nbsp;750&nbsp;руб.</b><br/><br/><span class="gray">Расчет произведен на легковой автомобиль по <a href="http://law.drom.ru/calc/region77/skoda/rapid/2016/110/">калькулятору транспортного налога</a> для Москвы (<a href="http://www.drom.ru/my_region/">изменить регион</a>).</span></div></div><br/>
<span class="label">Тип кузова:</span> хэтчбек<br/>
<span class="label">Цвет:</span> золотистый<br/>
<span class="label">Пробег:</span> <b>Новый автомобиль от официального дилера</b><br/>
<span class="label">Руль:</span> левый<br/>
<span class="label">VIN:</span> XW8AC1NH7HK****32<br/>
</div><p><span class="label">Данные по модели из каталога:</span>
<b>толян</b>
<b>4 515 руб.</b>
<b>Продажа Тойота Авенсис.</b>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

mileages = soup.find('span', text=u'Пробег:').find_next_sibling("b").get_text(strip=True)
print(mileages)
```

Prints:

```
Новый автомобиль от официального дилера
```

Comment: it return me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'`. When i try `mileages = soup.find('span', text=u'Пробег:')` it return me None

Comment: @user6241246 interesting, works for me as is - I pasted the code I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
b = None
spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"label"})
for span in spans:
    b = span.find("b")
    if b is not None:
        break
```

Then you can get access to text of "b" using:

```
b.text
```

Answer (score 0):

the following should work for you

```
spanTag = soup.find_all("span", string="Пробег:")
print spanTag[0].find_next_sibling("b")
print spanTag[0].find_next_sibling("b").string
```

result output:

```
<b>Новый автомобиль от официального дилера</b>
Новый автомобиль от официального дилера
```

cheers,

Dhiraj